# A simple question: how to download tweets at a specified time using "rtweets" package?

Tags: r

Just as the question shows, I want to download the tweets that were created a month ago. Could anyone tell me how to set the parameters? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+tweets+time

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What have you tried so far? What errors are you getting? Show us where you are stuck and we can help you make the next step